# Make use of the gmail api through a service account from the server side avoiding the OAUTH2 GUI

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I have an application developed in python that uses the SMPT service to connect to a gmail account. This type of connection is typified as an "Access of insecure applications" [lesssecureapps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

To remedy this I have set myself the task of updating my app, using the gmail api and for authentication to use a private key generated from a service account (without using G-Suit).

I have created a first proof of concept and it seems that it connects and authenticates correctly, but when trying to get the labels of the gmail account I get the following message:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">
```

I recap the steps I have followed to configure my google account:

1. I access [Google Api Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) and enable the use of the gmail api through the button that appears at the top: Enable apis and services
2. I access the credentials section, click on the top button: "create credentials" and select **Service account**
3. I create a service account and then generate a private key in json format

I add a small code snippet with my proof of concept and it that returns the error that I comment on the top:

```python
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build

    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/home/user/keys/privatekey_from_service_account.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No tienes labels.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
```

How can I solve my problem without using g-suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Precondition check failed."

Means that you are not allowed to do what you are trying to do.

> use a private key generated from a service account (without using G-Suit).

The Gmail api does not support service accounts for non gsuite domains.  You can only use a service account with a Gsuite domain account and gsuite domain emails.

Services account wont work with normal google gmail accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And how else can I use the Gmail api from the server side without interacting with the OAUTH GUI using a normal gemail account?

Comment: You can use Oauth2 to authenticate your application once store the refresh token, then use the refresh token every time you need to access the API.  This is your only option without gsuite.  TIP: I recommend looking into the verification process of an app using gmail scopes it can be quite expensive and time consuming its best to start the process early.