# Permanent authentication from cloud function

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am trying to host some code inside a cloud function. This code tracks and parses new e-mails and write some information to a Realtime Database. It is almost 100% finished, but as I am very beginner, it's been hard for me to deal with authentication. From my PC, it all worked when I authenticated just like it is shown [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_2_configure_the_sample). The problem is that this `token.json` file, which holds information about my login, is temporary. After some time, it needs to be deleted and I must login again. This login process is a browser tab that opens so I can choose my Google account.

However, my cloud function can't open browser tabs to login for me. So it must be able to stay logged in forever, or perform the login process without human interference. I feel like Google Dev guides are very unclear, at least for someone as inexperienced as I am. Here is a sample of what I have so far:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
client_secret_location = 'credentials.json'

def authentication():
    global creds
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', scopes)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port = 0)

        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

I guess `creds` is like a object holding my user session. It allows me to build my Gmail API and do all thing I must do with it:

```
gmail_session = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials = creds)
```

Howerever, as I said, this token expires after some days and it is needed to login again.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to mention that this function will be triggered by pub/sub.

Comment: take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/google/secret-manager-with-sendgrid) it seems to be a good and tested architecture for sending emails with Cloud Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable this so-called server-to-server authentication, you need a service account.
If your GMail account is part of a Google workspace, you can find instructions for creating such a service account here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726

As already explained here: [Make use of the gmail api through a service account from the server side avoiding the OAUTH2 GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914226/make-use-of-the-gmail-api-through-a-service-account-from-the-server-side-avoidin)
such service accounts are unfortunately only possible for gsuite (workspace) domains.

Comment: Yeah, I took long to find out that this was necessary. Thanks for your reply.